# PFSense - Deliver IPv6 over OpenVPN Tunnel

Tags: pfsense

I have an Gateway router and I am currently trying to set up a PFSense + OpenVPN Tunnel. However I am having problems with IPv6 connectivity.

The FGW is configured with the DMZ for the PFSense Internal IP.

Send below the PFSense configs:

PFSense in current configurations have IPv6 connectivity, but tunnel clients in tests give 0/10.

[image: Interface WAN]
WAN Interface

[image: Firewall WAN]
WAN Firewall

[image: Firewall OpenVPN]
OpenVPN Firewall

[image: OpenVPN Tunnel Config]
OpenVPN Tunnel Config